# SqlBulkCopy working perfect on local system. But when i upload my project to server. Its not working, not even showing any Error

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlbulkcopy

SqlBulkCopy: SqlBulkCopy working perfect on local system. But when i upload my project to server. Its not working, not even showing any Error. Thanks in advance.

code :

```
             try
                {
                    SqlConnection newcon = new SqlConnection(CS);

                    using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(newcon.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.Default))
                    {
                        // my DataTable column names match my SQL Column names, so I simply made this loop. However if your column names don't match, just pass in which datatable name matches the SQL column name in Column Mappings
                        foreach (DataColumn col in dtAllData.Columns)
                        {
                            String colName = col.ColumnName;
                             //bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(clmn.ColumnName, clmn.ColumnName)
                            bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(colName, "[" + col.ColumnName + "]");
                        }
                        newcon.Open();
                        bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 99999999;
                        bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = tableQueryTableName;
                        bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtAllData);
                    }
                    newcon.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    string msg = ex.Message;
                }
```

Comment: If the source and destination data have the same column names, you don't need to map them. This should be done automatically. Also are you sure that the names match case, etc?

Comment: In addition to @Dom answer, how this line "string msg = ex.Message;" could show an error anyway... You don't seem to log it anywhere

Answer (score 0):

Ran across a similar issue recently and my solution was to check if you have anything in the data table itself.

I was downloading some data from an open source API and inserting into data table and bulk inserting into SQL. It works fine on my local machine but failed on the server. After many hours of debugging, the issue was server doesn't have outbound traffic. So no data to insert from the server.